# A one way Function provably reversible at N applications with the same seed?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, reference-request, one-way-function, key-reuse

I'm looking for a function that is generally one way from some secret $F(s, A) \rightarrow Y$, where $A$ is known, $Y$ is produced (also known), and $s$ is kept secret. But whose repeated application results in the function being reversible (to determine $s$) at some step $F_n$.

**Edit:** $A[1,2 \dots n]$ is a set of numbers not known in advance (prior to each successive application of $F$), but of a particular type, say the first 16 bytes of a SHA-256.

It is essential that it can be proven that the function is not reversible at $n-1$ (or that the work necessary to reverse at $n-1$ is very high) and sufficiently easy to reverse at $n$ ($n+1$ etc.), and that this is provable for any s belonging to a certain group.

$F(s, A_1) \rightarrow Y_1\\
F(s, A_2) \rightarrow Y_2 \\
\dots \\
F(s, A_3) \rightarrow Y_n$

Would greatly appreciate a pointer in the right direction (what functions to look at, or even some reading on the subject), thanks.

Comment: "being reversible at some step N" in the sense of revealing the original A or the immediately preceding A? $\;\;\;$

Comment: A1..A2..An are known values, put through some function (or hash) along with secret s. The idea is to be able to determine s, after Fn operations.

Comment: Do you want `s` to remain hidden against an essentially unbounded number of queries that don't include any such chains, or just against less than N _total_ queries? $\;$

Comment: just against less than N total queries, and for any s from a certain Set S. That is to say, that an observer who knowing someone choose a seed s from Set S, would be able to derive s after N applications of some Function F to s and known A[1,2..n].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F(s,A) can be

a [prefix-free encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) of the number of elements in the finite field encoded by s

[||](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) $\:$ the polynomial R (as described at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Effective_polynomial_representation)) from that finite field $\;$ [||](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)

the output of the degree-at-most-(N-1) polynomial encoded by s over that finite field at the point A

.
Let SP be the set of polynomials of degree at most N-1 over the finite field. $\:$ N input-output pairs would allow one to efficiently find the encoded element of SP by [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). $\:$ Observe that for any given field, for all A, evaluate-at-A is a linear map from SP to the field. $\:$ Since Lagrange interpolation will always give a compatible polynomial (and not just find one when there is one), that linear map is surjective. $\:$ Thus, for all integers x in {0,1,2,3,...,N-2,N-1}, for any
given N-x input-output pairs and any given z other inputs, the outputs at those x inputs for such a polynomial chosen uniformly from the subset of SP that produces the given N-x input-output pairs are independent and uniformly distributed. $\:$ Observe that any guess at s can only be correct if it gets those outputs correct.

Therefore, for all integers x in {0,1,2,3,...,N-2,N-1}, the probability of guessing s correctly is

at most [[the sampling error for SP] plus [one over [[the number of elements in the field] to the x]]].

[This wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic) describes how to do arithmetic over finite fields given an irreducible polynomial over

their characteristic field. $\:$ [This paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.html) gives the "simplest" such polynomials for degree at most 10000

over the field with 2 elements, and [these](http://istina.msu.ru/media/publications/articles/f44/bf3/1951350/IgorGash.pdf) two [papers](http://digitalcommons.iwu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1013&context=math_honproj) give algorithms which can let you confirm that

those polynomials are in fact irreducible (confirming that they're the *simplest* would be harder).

More generally, over small prime fields, [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-54-189/S0025-5718-1990-0993933-0/S0025-5718-1990-0993933-0.pdf) gives a deterministic algorithm

for constructing irreducible polynomials and [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00124895) gives constructions that

are presumably more efficient for degrees divisible by a not-too-small power of 2.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Shamir's secret sharing, uses a0 = s in the terms of the polynomial over a finite field of size p, where as it sounds like you are suggesting for f a polynomial of degree n-1 whose terms are known over a finite field of size s (which is not known)?

Comment: No, I was suggesting that f be evaluation of s at A, where s is a polynomial of degree at most N-1. $\:$ However, I now realize that the decoder also needs to know _what the finite field is_. $\hspace{1.45 in}$